# question about least squares regression between two matrices

Tags: regression, dolphindb

I looked at the function "ols" that calculates ordinary least squares regression :

```py
ols(Y, X, [intercept=true], [mode=0])
```

Here the dependent variable Y must be a vector, not a matrix, so how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the higher-order function [cross(func, X, [Y])](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/cross.html) to traverse the calculation in units of columns:

```py
pcross(ols, X, matrixY)
```

If x is a vector, it can be implemented as follows:

```py
each(ols{,x}, matrixY)
```